# How to translate my cURL command into Chrome command?

Tags: google-chrome, curl

I want to fire a POST request in command line, to post my image to a image searching site. At first, I tried cURL and get this command which works:

```
curl -i -X POST -F file=@search.png http://saucenao.com/search.php
```

It will post a file in FORM to the searching site and returns a HTML page result full with JavaScript which makes it hard to read in terminal. And it's also hard to preview online image in terminal.

Then I remember that I can open Chrome with arguments in command line, which I think may solve my problem. After some digging, I found Chrome switches, but seams it's just about Chrome starting flags (I'm not sure is this right, but I didn't find how to fire a post request like cURL do.)

So, can I use Chrome in command line to start it with a POST request just like my cURL command above?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things you could do.

1. You could write a script in JavaScript that will send the POST request and display the results inside the `<body>` element or the like;
2. You could keep the cURL command and use the `-o` (or `--output`) to save the resulting HTML in a file (but lose the `-i` switch, to avoid having the headers in the file), then open the file in Chrome or whichever browser you prefer. You could combine the two commands as a one-liner in any operating system. If you use Ubuntu, for example:

   `$ curl -o search.html -X POST -F file=@search.png http://saucenao.com/search.php && google-chrome search.html && rm search.html`
3. According to [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/844249) you could use `bcat` in order to avoid using a temporary file. Install it by `apt-get install ruby-bcat` and then just run

   `$ curl -X POST -F file=@search.png http://saucenao.com/search.php | bcat`

I think the easier option is #2, but whichever you prefer.

Comment: I'm not sure what your first option mean, do you mean something like `google-chrome "javascript:(function(){ something here... })()`?

Comment: BTW, I don't like the extra tempt file in option 2, can that be removed?

Comment: No, I don't think that'll work as you'll need an actual HTML document to run the JS in and more importantly, display the results in.
You would have to create a minimal HTML file which will contain the script and trigger a POST request (either by submitting a preset form or by an XHR).

Comment: Added a third option that avoids a temp file altogether.

Comment: `bcat` is a good suggestion, but this will occur cross origin and also image protection problem. I think scripting Chrome to open `http://saucenao.com/search.php` would be a better choice.

Comment: @kxxoling Do you think `bcat` will issue cross-origin/hotlinking problems? AFAIK `bcat` just streams the stdin to the browser. If the cURL command succeeds, so will the streaming – `bcat` does _not_ send out a separate request to the server. Of course, the browser might.